# MySQL SELECT item where item is in table 6 times

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT app_date, app_time FROM appointments
```

I am looking to add on to it. Say if I have 6 records where the app_date is Dec 1st and the app_time is 1:00pm then show that record in my select....is this possible? Kinda new to MySQL, this is kinda out of my league.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT app_date, app_time FROM appointments
GROUP BY app_date, app_time
having count(*) >=6
```

Comment: I think the OP was using 6 as an example only it might make more sense to leave the HAVING clause off the query.